# Appending element to subelement using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append a div element to the table dynamically. I use the below code but it does not append correctly

**Html**

```
<table id="foo">
  <tr id="row1"><td>FOO</td> </tr>
  <tr id="row2"><td>BAR</td></tr>
  <tr id="row3"><td>APPENDING</td></tr>
  <tr id="row4"><td>ELEMENT</td></tr>
  <tr id="row5"><td>JQUERY</td></tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("input").on("click",function(){
   console.log($("#row3"))
   $("#row3").append("<tr id='foo1'><td>Appending div</td></tr>");
});
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/zX64K/1/)

But the code append the element to that row(**row3**). I try to append the div before the element **row3** I know only the ID of the element and **.children() or .eq()** is not working for this purpose. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: All DOM manipulation methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/.

Comment: FYI even if you want to "append" do it on table or tbody scope never on tr or td scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) then:

```
$("input").on("click", function() {
   $("#row3").before("<tr id='foo1'><td>Appending div</td></tr>");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zX64K/2/